# I can't do this 301 wordpress redirect

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect all of my 2.5 million pages from my website to a URL that adds another bar.

For example:

```
https://www.example.com/my-url-is-here/perfil
```

to

```
https://www.example.com/enterprise/my-url-is-here/perfil
```

htaccess or php header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you need to add `/enterprise` at the start of the URL-path. I'm assuming you need to exclude requests that otherwise map to static files (like images, CSS, JS and the WordPress front-controller `index.php` itself). Add the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.\w{2,4}$
RewriteRule !^enterprise https://www.example.com/enterprise%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The above states, if the requested URL-path does not start `/enterprise` and  does not end with what looks like a file-extension then redirect, prefixing the URL-path with `/enterprise`.

I'm assuming all static resources include a standard file extension (`.css`, `.js`, `.png`, etc.) and your WordPress URLs don't look like they have a file extension, eg. not of the form `.html` etc. This simple pattern match avoids the more expensive filesystem check.

Include the full canoncial URL (ie. `https://www.example.com/`) to avoid multiple redirects when requesting the non-canonical URL.

Test first with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.

**UPDATE#1:**

> I do not need to redirect the entire site, but only in URLs ending in `/perfil` or `/perfil/amp`

In that case, you can add another condition to match these URLs. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.\w{2,4}$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /perfil(/amp)?$
RewriteRule !^enterprise https://www.example.com/enterprise%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

**UPDATE#2:**

> there are still some urls that I would like to be redirected by adding / enterprise, but these do not have the termination `/perfil` or `/amp` Example: `example.com/my-url-is-here` and I would like to be redirected to: `example.com/enterprise/my-url-is-here/perfil`

These would seem to be "special cases", so you'll need to add a separate directive for each "special" URL.

For example, the following can be placed before or after the rule above:

```
RewriteRule ^my-url-is-here$ https://www.example.com/enterprise/$0/perfil [R=301,L]
```

`$0` is a backreference to the entire URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

**UPDATE#3:**

> ...all urls must necessarily contain the following words `/enterprise/my-url-is-here/perfil` or `/enterprise/my-url-is-here/perfil/amp`

If *all* URLs must be redirected then yes you can implement a single rule. However, you can't obviously redirect to `.../perfil` *or* `.../perfil/amp` - you need to decide on one or the other.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(enterprise|perfil)(/|$)
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ https://www.example.com/enterprise/$1/perfil [R=301,L]
```

The above redirects all requests for single path segment URLs, where that path segment can only consist of the characters `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_` (underscore) or `-` (hyphen) and redirects to a URL of the form `/enterprise/<url>/perfil`.

It will redirect `/foo` or `/foo/`, but not `/something/foo` or `/foo/something` or `/enterprise` or `/perfil` (if they could be valid requests?).

The `$1` backreference contains the captured URL-path less the trailing slash (if any).

Comment: Our! That was incredible! I had achieved nothing like this. We just need to correct something. The way it is modifies the entire site and I do not need to redirect the entire site, but only in urls ending in /perfil or /perfil/amp - is it possible to do this filter without changing the other pages?

Comment: It is like this:
RewriteCond% {REQUEST_URI}! \. \ W {2,4} $
RewriteRule! ^ Enterprise https://www.example.com/enterprise%{REQUEST_URI} [R = 302, L]

Comment: You can add another condition to match just those URLs. I've updated my answer. (I can't read your comment with the code sample - it looks like you've introduced a lot of erroneous spacing?! Use backticks to format "short" inline code in comments, but otherwise code samples need to be added to your question to retain formatting.)

Comment: Dude, I just have to thank you. Worked perfectly. Thank you very much, you have no idea how grateful I am for that!

Comment: Marked! You seem to be an expert in regular expression, thanks again!

Comment: But a doubt arose, there are still some urls that I would like to be redirected by adding / enterprise, but these do not have the termination /perfil or /amp
Example: https://www.example.com/my-url-is-here
and I would like to be redirected to:
https://www.example.com/enterprise/my-url-is-here/perfil 
Could you help me with this one?

Comment: I don't know if I understood correctly, but I would have to manually add the urls, if it is not viable, since there are almost 2.5 million urls.

Comment: How do you differentiate between `/url-to-be-redirected` and `/url-should-not-be-redirected`? Or, should all other URLs be redirected?

Comment: because Google has indexed both https://www.example.com/my-url-is-here/perfil and https://www.example.com/my-url-is-here as valid pages. But I want to leave only the first url in searches.

Comment: Yes, but... do you want to redirect _all_ other URLs or just "some URLs" as you suggest? If you only want to redirect "some" and you wish to "automate" this with a few simple rules then you need to be able to differentiate between the URLs that should be redirected and those that should not. What is different about the URLs that should be redirected? If you can't differentiate (ie. there is no discernable difference in the URL pattern) then you will need to redirect one-by-one. However, if WordPress "knows" which URLs should be redirected then you could perform the redirect in WP instead. (?)

Comment: the difference will not be found in the url /profile or /amp all, that is, all urls must necessarily contain the following words /enterprise/my-url-is-here/perfil or /enterprise/my-url-is-here/perfil/amp

Comment: Ok, so _all_ URLs need to be redirected. Although you need to decide wheich URL you redirect to, ie. `.../perfil` OR `.../perfil/amp`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: It worked fine, but I still have a little problem. I need the redirect to ignore about 5 urls. Can I leave this condition more?